# Data visualization show and hide using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I need to make the following visualization using d3.js, as I am new to d3, I am facing a lot of problems in doing this.

[image]

I have a column of categories for which I have a dataset:

```
var dataset=[
          {label: name1,
          value: 5,
          },
          {label: subname1,
          value: 2,
          },
          {label: sub1,
          value: 1,
          },
          {label: sub2,
          value: 2,
          },
          {label: subname2,
          value: 1,
          },
          {label: sub3,
          value: 1,
          },
          {label: subname3,
           value: 1,
          },
          {label: sub4,
           value: 1,
          },
          {label: subname4,
          value: 1,
          },
          {label: sub5,
          value: 1,
          },
          {label: sub6,
           value: 1,
          },
          {label: subname5,
          value: 1,
          }
     ]
```

The contribution comes from the value and the name comes from label the sub-name column should be visible only if I click name categories and the "sub" category should visible only if I click sub-name category.

In the same way the contribution also should appear only if I click the respective category could someone help in this.

Jsfiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sai20/q0jtnxzz/1/).

Comment: i am trying to do the below but it was really not at all perfect so, its better not to see the code
https://jsfiddle.net/sai20/q0jtnxzz/1/

Comment: can you help me in doing this @AndyLewis hope u understood the question 
if this is not possible suggest me any alternative solutions for this pls!!

Comment: We will need at least the html you have used in the fiddle too. As it stands the question is too vague to answer. Sorry.

Comment: @AndyLewis there is no much of html

Comment: @AndyLewis i updated the fiddle file u can see it here now with html code too. https://jsfiddle.net/sai20/q0jtnxzz/4/